# Handling 403 Response in TypeScript and PHP by Showing UI Message and Suppressing Console

Tags: php, typescript, symfony

I have a server-side PHP function that sends a 403 Forbidden response if the user does not have the appropriate permissions. On the client side, I am using TypeScript to fetch a URL and handle the response. Currently, my client-side code handles the response by logging errors to the console. However, I want to modify my code to handle a 403 response by showing a message to the user in the UI and suppressing the console output.

Here is my server-side PHP function:

```php
#[Route(path: '/set-order', name: 'subject_set_order', methods: ['POST'])]
public function setOrderAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $order = $request->getContent();
    $order = json_decode($order, true);

    foreach ($order as $id => $index) {
        $subject = $this->subjectRepository->find((int)$id);
        if (!($subject instanceof CommunitySubject)) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Subject not found'], 404);
        }

        try {
            $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('subject_edit', $subject->getCommunity());
        } catch (AccessDeniedException $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Access denied'], 403);
        }

        $subject->setOrder((int)$index);
    }

    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return new JsonResponse();
}
```

And here is my TypeScript code:

```js
type orderObject = {
    [key: string]: number
};

function updateOrder(container: HTMLElement): void {

    const order: orderObject = {};

    getDraggableElements(container).forEach((draggableElement: HTMLElement, index: number): void => {
        const subjectId: number = getSubjectId(draggableElement);
        order[subjectId] = index;
    });

    sendOrderPostRequest(order);
}

function sendOrderPostRequest(order: orderObject): void {

    const url: string = `${window.location.href}/subject/set-order`;

    fetch(url, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(order),
    })
    .then((response: Response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            handleError();
        }

        return response.json();
    });
}

function handleError(): void {
    const errorMessageElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('error-message');
    if (! errorMessageElement) {
        return;
    }

    errorMessageElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    errorMessageElement.innerText = 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
}
```

I tried sending a POST request using the `fetch` function in my TypeScript code and handling the response in the `sendOrderPostRequest` function. If the response is not ok (e.g., 403, 404), I called the `handleError` function to show an error message in the UI.

Note:
Currently, I am using the following line at the top of my PHP function to force a 403 response for testing purposes, but I will remove this line later:

```php
return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Access denied'], 403);
```

I included this line to force a 403 response so that I can test my client-side code. However, I am still seeing the error in the console. How can I modify my TypeScript code to handle the 403 response by showing a message in the UI and not log the error in the console?

I was expecting that this approach would handle the 403 response by showing a message to the user in the UI and suppressing the console output. While my approach correctly handles showing the message in the UI, it does not suppress the console output because the browser automatically logs HTTP errors like 403 and 404 to the console, and this behavior cannot be controlled from my client-side code is there any otherway?.

Comment: _"because the browser automatically logs HTTP errors like 403 and 404 to the console, and this behavior cannot be controlled from my client-side code"_ - yes, that's exactly the case. What you want, is not possible.